# SimplyScroll breaks on this page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, simplyscroll

Why can't simplyscroll handle this div which has nested divs?

ADDED INFO

The scrolling isn't done.  You click on the buttons, and no scrolling happens.  If I change the contents of the div, to plain text, the scrolling works.  This is saying that simplyscroll has trouble with the nested divs and the tags in them.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Simply Scroll</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/jquery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script -->   

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css">

<!-- script type="text/javascript" src="/simplyscroll/jquery.simplyscroll-1.0.4.js"></script -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://simplyscroll.googlecode.com/files/jquery.simplyscroll-1.0.4.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/simplyscroll/jquery.simplyscroll-1.0.4.css" media="all" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $("#scroller").simplyScroll({
            className: 'vert',
            horizontal: false,
            frameRate: 20,
            speed: 5            
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="scroller">
    <div id="u0014" class="comurl"> <img class="dhandle" src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=tf1.fr" align="middle" />&nbsp;<a href="http://tf1.fr" target="_blank" onmouseOver="url_preview('show', this, 'editdiv');" onmouseOut="url_preview('hide', this, 'editdiv');" >TF1.fr</a> <img src="/images/spacer.png" class="spacer" /> <img class="urlbutton" title="Edit" src="/icodeact/Edit16.png" onClick=""/> <img class="urlbutton" title="Delete" src="/icodeact/Delete16.png" onClick="delete_url('u0014');"/> 
    </div>
    <div id="u0015" class="comurl"> <img class="dhandle" src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=www.aol.com" align="middle" />&nbsp;<a href="http://www.aol.com" target="_blank" onmouseOver="url_preview('show', this, 'editdiv');" onmouseOut="url_preview('hide', this, 'editdiv');" >AOL.com</a> <img src="/images/spacer.png" class="spacer" /> <img class="urlbutton" title="Edit" src="/icodeact/Edit16.png" onClick=""/> <img class="urlbutton" src="/icodeact/Delete16.png" onClick="delete_url('u0015');"/> 
    </div>
    <div id="u0016" class="comurl"> <img class="dhandle" src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=www.facebook.com" align="middle" />&nbsp;<a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank" onmouseOver="url_preview('show', this, 'editdiv');" onmouseOut="url_preview('hide', this, 'editdiv');" >Facebook.com</a>  <img src="/images/spacer.png" class="spacer" /> <img class="urlbutton" title="Edit" src="/icodeact/Edit16.png" onClick=""/> <img class="urlbutton" src="/icodeact/Delete16.png" onClick="delete_url('u0014');"/>
    </div>
    <div id="u0017" class="comurl"> <img class="dhandle" src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=tf1.fr" align="middle" />&nbsp;<a href="http://tf1.fr" target="_blank" onmouseOver="url_preview('show', this, 'editdiv');" onmouseOut="url_preview('hide', this, 'editdiv');" >TF1.fr</a> <img src="/images/spacer.png" class="spacer" /> <img class="urlbutton" title="Edit" src="/icodeact/Edit16.png" onClick=""/> <img class="urlbutton" title="Delete" src="/icodeact/Delete16.png" onClick="delete_url('u0014');"/> 
    </div>
    <div id="u0018" class="comurl"> <img class="dhandle" src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=www.aol.com" align="middle" />&nbsp;<a href="http://www.aol.com" target="_blank" onmouseOver="url_preview('show', this, 'editdiv');" onmouseOut="url_preview('hide', this, 'editdiv');" >AOL.com</a> <img src="/images/spacer.png" class="spacer" /> <img class="urlbutton" title="Edit" src="/icodeact/Edit16.png" onClick=""/> <img class="urlbutton" src="/icodeact/Delete16.png" onClick="delete_url('u0015');"/> 
    </div>
    <div id="u0019" class="comurl"> <img class="dhandle" src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=www.facebook.com" align="middle" />&nbsp;<a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank" onmouseOver="url_preview('show', this, 'editdiv');" onmouseOut="url_preview('hide', this, 'editdiv');" >Facebook.com</a>  <img src="/images/spacer.png" class="spacer" /> <img class="urlbutton" title="Edit" src="/icodeact/Edit16.png" onClick=""/> <img class="urlbutton" src="/icodeact/Delete16.png" onClick="delete_url('u0014');"/>
    </div>
    <div id="u0020" class="comurl"> <img class="dhandle" src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=tf1.fr" align="middle" />&nbsp;<a href="http://tf1.fr" target="_blank" onmouseOver="url_preview('show', this, 'editdiv');" onmouseOut="url_preview('hide', this, 'editdiv');" >TF1.fr</a> <img src="/images/spacer.png" class="spacer" /> <img class="urlbutton" title="Edit" src="/icodeact/Edit16.png" onClick=""/> <img class="urlbutton" title="Delete" src="/icodeact/Delete16.png" onClick="delete_url('u0014');"/> 
    </div>
    <div id="u0021" class="comurl"> <img class="dhandle" src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=www.aol.com" align="middle" />&nbsp;<a href="http://www.aol.com" target="_blank" onmouseOver="url_preview('show', this, 'editdiv');" onmouseOut="url_preview('hide', this, 'editdiv');" >AOL.com</a> <img src="/images/spacer.png" class="spacer" /> <img class="urlbutton" title="Edit" src="/icodeact/Edit16.png" onClick=""/> <img class="urlbutton" src="/icodeact/Delete16.png" onClick="delete_url('u0015');"/> 
    </div>
    <div id="u0023" class="comurl"> <img class="dhandle" src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=www.facebook.com" align="middle" />&nbsp;<a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank" onmouseOver="url_preview('show', this, 'editdiv');" onmouseOut="url_preview('hide', this, 'editdiv');" >Facebook.com</a>  <img src="/images/spacer.png" class="spacer" /> <img class="urlbutton" title="Edit" src="/icodeact/Edit16.png" onClick=""/> <img class="urlbutton" src="/icodeact/Delete16.png" onClick="delete_url('u0014');"/>
    </div>
    <div id="u0024" class="comurl"> <img class="dhandle" src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=tf1.fr" align="middle" />&nbsp;<a href="http://tf1.fr" target="_blank" onmouseOver="url_preview('show', this, 'editdiv');" onmouseOut="url_preview('hide', this, 'editdiv');" >TF1.fr</a> <img src="/images/spacer.png" class="spacer" /> <img class="urlbutton" title="Edit" src="/icodeact/Edit16.png" onClick=""/> <img class="urlbutton" title="Delete" src="/icodeact/Delete16.png" onClick="delete_url('u0014');"/> 
    </div>
    <div id="u0025" class="comurl"> <img class="dhandle" src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=www.aol.com" align="middle" />&nbsp;<a href="http://www.aol.com" target="_blank" onmouseOver="url_preview('show', this, 'editdiv');" onmouseOut="url_preview('hide', this, 'editdiv');" >AOL.com</a> <img src="/images/spacer.png" class="spacer" /> <img class="urlbutton" title="Edit" src="/icodeact/Edit16.png" onClick=""/> <img class="urlbutton" src="/icodeact/Delete16.png" onClick="delete_url('u0015');"/> 
    </div>
    <div id="u0026" class="comurl"> <img class="dhandle" src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=www.facebook.com" align="middle" />&nbsp;<a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank" onmouseOver="url_preview('show', this, 'editdiv');" onmouseOut="url_preview('hide', this, 'editdiv');" >Facebook.com</a>  <img src="/images/spacer.png" class="spacer" /> <img class="urlbutton" title="Edit" src="/icodeact/Edit16.png" onClick=""/> <img class="urlbutton" src="/icodeact/Delete16.png" onClick="delete_url('u0014');"/>
    </div>
    <div id="u0028" class="comurl"> <img class="dhandle" src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=www.facebook.com" align="middle" />&nbsp;<a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank" onmouseOver="url_preview('show', this, 'editdiv');" onmouseOut="url_preview('hide', this, 'editdiv');" >Facebook.com</a>  <img src="/images/spacer.png" class="spacer" /> <img class="urlbutton" title="Edit" src="/icodeact/Edit16.png" onClick=""/> <img class="urlbutton" src="/icodeact/Delete16.png" onClick="delete_url('u0014');"/>
    </div>
    <div id="u0029" class="comurl"> <img class="dhandle" src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=tf1.fr" align="middle" />&nbsp;<a href="http://tf1.fr" target="_blank" onmouseOver="url_preview('show', this, 'editdiv');" onmouseOut="url_preview('hide', this, 'editdiv');" >TF1.fr</a> <img src="/images/spacer.png" class="spacer" /> <img class="urlbutton" title="Edit" src="/icodeact/Edit16.png" onClick=""/> <img class="urlbutton" title="Delete" src="/icodeact/Delete16.png" onClick="delete_url('u0014');"/> 
    </div>
    <div id="u0030" class="comurl"> <img class="dhandle" src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=www.aol.com" align="middle" />&nbsp;<a href="http://www.aol.com" target="_blank" onmouseOver="url_preview('show', this, 'editdiv');" onmouseOut="url_preview('hide', this, 'editdiv');" >AOL.com</a> <img src="/images/spacer.png" class="spacer" /> <img class="urlbutton" title="Edit" src="/icodeact/Edit16.png" onClick=""/> <img class="urlbutton" src="/icodeact/Delete16.png" onClick="delete_url('u0015');"/> 
    </div>
    <div id="u0031" class="comurl"> <img class="dhandle" src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=www.facebook.com" align="middle" />&nbsp;<a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank" onmouseOver="url_preview('show', this, 'editdiv');" onmouseOut="url_preview('hide', this, 'editdiv');" >Facebook.com</a>  <img src="/images/spacer.png" class="spacer" /> <img class="urlbutton" title="Edit" src="/icodeact/Edit16.png" onClick=""/> <img class="urlbutton" src="/icodeact/Delete16.png" onClick="delete_url('u0014');"/>
    </div>           
    <div id="u0032" class="comurl"> <img class="dhandle" src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=www.facebook.com" align="middle" />&nbsp;<a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank" onmouseOver="url_preview('show', this, 'editdiv');" onmouseOut="url_preview('hide', this, 'editdiv');" >Facebook.com</a>  <img src="/images/spacer.png" class="spacer" /> <img class="urlbutton" title="Edit" src="/icodeact/Edit16.png" onClick=""/> <img class="urlbutton" src="/icodeact/Delete16.png" onClick="delete_url('u0014');"/>
    </div>
    <div id="u0033" class="comurl"> <img class="dhandle" src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=tf1.fr" align="middle" />&nbsp;<a href="http://tf1.fr" target="_blank" onmouseOver="url_preview('show', this, 'editdiv');" onmouseOut="url_preview('hide', this, 'editdiv');" >TF1.fr</a> <img src="/images/spacer.png" class="spacer" /> <img class="urlbutton" title="Edit" src="/icodeact/Edit16.png" onClick=""/> <img class="urlbutton" title="Delete" src="/icodeact/Delete16.png" onClick="delete_url('u0014');"/> 
    </div>
    <div id="u0034" class="comurl"> <img class="dhandle" src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=www.aol.com" align="middle" />&nbsp;<a href="http://www.aol.com" target="_blank" onmouseOver="url_preview('show', this, 'editdiv');" onmouseOut="url_preview('hide', this, 'editdiv');" >AOL.com</a> <img src="/images/spacer.png" class="spacer" /> <img class="urlbutton" title="Edit" src="/icodeact/Edit16.png" onClick=""/> <img class="urlbutton" src="/icodeact/Delete16.png" onClick="delete_url('u0015');"/> 
    </div>
    <div id="u0035" class="comurl"> <img class="dhandle" src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=www.facebook.com" align="middle" />&nbsp;<a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank" onmouseOver="url_preview('show', this, 'editdiv');" onmouseOut="url_preview('hide', this, 'editdiv');" >Facebook.com</a>  <img src="/images/spacer.png" class="spacer" /> <img class="urlbutton" title="Edit" src="/icodeact/Edit16.png" onClick=""/> <img class="urlbutton" src="/icodeact/Delete16.png" onClick="delete_url('u0014');"/>
    </div>           


    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please be more specific about the problem you are having.

Comment: @Anson The scrolling isn't done.  You click on the buttons, and no scrolling happens.  If I change the contents of the div, to plain text, the scrolling works.  This is saying that simplyscroll has trouble with the nested divs and the tags in them.

Comment: You're using jQuery so there's no reason to have all that inline JavaScript.

Comment: Your code, just as you posted it, seems to be working fine in this JSFiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/jUXUG/

Comment: @Sparky672 The line at the beginning of my HTML did that.  `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`. Why could that be?

Comment: You need to have valid code.  Your code cannot be validated unless you specify the corresponding `DOCTYPE`.  Browsers can go wonky (IE goes into quirks mode) when a page is missing the `DOCTYPE` or not validated.   http://validator.w3.org

Comment: @Sparky672 When I debugged my code I found that it actually works if I remove that line.  That line breaks the simplyscroll.  Only `<html>` is required at the beginning of the file.  I am asking why the other information would cause simplyscroll to break.

Comment: Did you run your page through the W3C validator?  (You have 88 validator errors).  It will also give you an error if you leave out the `Doctype`.  You can see that it runs fine inside my JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found different code to do the continuous scrolling like SimplyScroll.

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
            $(document).ready(function($) { 
               $(".scrolling_prev", $("#'.$node['ID'].'")).mousedown(function() { 
                    startScrolling($(".link_drop_box", $("#'.$node['ID'].'")), "-=50px"); 
                }).mouseup(function() { 
                    $(".link_drop_box", $("#'.$node['ID'].'")).stop() 
                }); 
                $(".scrolling_next", $("#'.$node['ID'].'")).mousedown(function() { 
                    startScrolling($(".link_drop_box", $("#'.$node['ID'].'")), "+=50px"); 
                }).mouseup(function() { 
                    $(".link_drop_box", $("#'.$node['ID'].'")).stop(); 
                }); 
            }); 
</script>
```